# what is the equivalent file of opcheckout.js(which is in magento 1) in magento 2

Tags: checkout, javascript, payment-methods, magento2.2.2, file

**Magento 1**

> /var/www/html/xxx/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js

**Magento 2**

What is the equivalent file for above one in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single file. JavaScript in Magento 2 is working totally different. It uses:

- **RequireJS** to load JavaScript files and requirements
- **Knockout.js** for rendering the checkout (and the admin area).
- A system called **UI Components** for configuration and retrieval of data (only in checkout and the admin area).

It's quite complicated and too much to explain here. If you want a first introduction, I recommend reading https://inviqa.de/blog/technical-guide-magento-2-checkout.